# Active Directory, 2 Domain Controllers, SAN Storage and Folder Redirection

Tags: active-directory, storage-area-network, file-server, folder-redirection

Greeting's, I'm provided with:

1. Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition.
2. SAN block storage (EMC VNXe 1600) with FC connectivity.
3. 2 Blade servers (Dell M630 within M1000e chassis) with FC switch. Each server has 2 Xeon V3 processors totalling 32 cores and 64 GB DDR4 RAM.

I need to implement active directory with **2 domain controllers** and **folder redirection** for all users (user count is at 250 and will reach 1000 in due course). Folder redirection will be used for all customizable folders.

Problem / Question:

1. A LUN created on SAN storage can only be mounted on one server (Domain controller). Mounting single LUN on multiple servers **will** corrupt the LUN.
2. Folder redirection will require ACLs to keep user data secure (ACLs are mentioned here: (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649078(v=ws.11).aspx). I see that these are NTFS ACLs.

Given the above constraints (hardware / software / requirements). How best can I implement 2 DCs with folder redirection? I have one extra server which I can use.

I have got certain recommendations such as creating a filer server but I'm unaware if the I/O will be acceptable in case where DC's are constantly asking a file server to read, write user data?

What would be the best way to go about implementing folder redirection in this case?

Comment: Maybe this topic will be helpful for you https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1952487-implementing-folder-redirection

Comment: Since you have Windows Servers, I would suggest you look at Cluster Shared Volumes. The implementation of those on top of NTFS will provide you with shared storage, illuminating I/O corruption due to MPIO.